# Plugin Development: how to add plugin to the Eclipse "Quick Access" for all perspectives

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created a very simple command contribution plugin. However it's visible in the "Quick Access" only when I make it available via **Window -> Customize Perspective -> Command Groups Availability**. Is it possible to make it available for the "Quick Access" for all perspectives regardless of the "Command Group Availability" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gist & solution to the problem are the following:

**Gist of the issue**

The command is contributed as an `actionSet`, which ties it to be active in a perspective (it will also add it to the menus and toolbars)

**Solution**

Need to write a `command` and make sure the `actionSet` action sets the - `definitionId` to the `commandId`.  Then write a **[defaultHandler](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_cmd_handlers.htm)** for the command, the one that will work in the general case (by default it will add the command to the **Quick Access** regardless of the perspective).

The answer was also posted to the [Eclipse community forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1698579/#msg_1698579).